# Custom loss function

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have been working on a new loss function, my input Tensors runs through a series of `math.ops` manipulation and several calls of `tf.map_fn`. 
After I feed my cost to the optimizer, it says that there is no gradients. 
My question is somehow generic, what is the steps for creating a new loss function.

Comment: You need at least to define the gradient of your function if it cannot be computed by tensorflow. The gradient of your custom loss function is necessary for the back-propagation algorithm that updates the weights in your model

Comment: could you provide some simple working example ?